# What's happening while PySide2 load and create component?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qml, pyside2

This example is working:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlComponent
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView

app = QGuiApplication()
view = QQuickView()
engine = view.engine()
url = QUrl("main.qml")
view.setSource(url)
component = QQmlComponent(engine, QUrl.fromLocalFile("block.qml"))
item = component.create()
item.setParent(view.rootObject())
item.setParentItem(view.rootObject())
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

The item is a class of QQuickItem.
The component.create() is a class of QQuickItem.
After change this example to:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlComponent
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView

app = QGuiApplication()
view = QQuickView()
engine = view.engine()
url = QUrl("main.qml")
view.setSource(url)
item = QQmlComponent(engine, QUrl.fromLocalFile("block.qml")).create()
item.setParent(view.rootObject())
item.setParentItem(view.rootObject())
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

It's throw the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/babywolf/dev/apps/qttest/test.py", line 14, in <module>     
item.setParent(view.rootObject())
RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtQuick.QQuickItem) already deleted.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

What's wrong?

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "green"
}
```

block.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Text {
    text: "Hello World"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a particular behavior of PySide that if a variable is not assigned to an object it is eliminated so in this case QQmlComponent is created but not assigned to a variable so it will be removed unlike the first case since it is assigned to the variable `component`, so when wanting to create the item the component no longer exists generating that error.

One solution is to pass a parent as in this case can be view extending its life cycle:

```
item = QQmlComponent(engine, QUrl.fromLocalFile("block.qml"), view).create()
#                                                               └----- parent
```